# Rebinding Backbone 1.0 observers of a model to a different model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Is it possible to rebind all the observers (or is it "listeners") of a Backbone 1.0 model to a new model of the same type?

What I have is a sessionManager object:

```js
var SessionManager = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // a function sets up a new Order as an attribute of `this`.

    // later another function sets a different (new) Order object in this same attribute like so:
    someFunction: function(customerId) {
        // Order is also a Backbone Model
        this.set('order', new Order({customerId: 10001}));          
    }

});

var sessionManager = new SessionManager();
```

So, at a certain point in the application the `order` attribute of the `sessionManager` is `set` to a `new Order({customerId: 10002})`.

What I would like to happen at this point is that the previous `order` notifies all it's observers to stop listening to it and instead to listen to the `new Order({customerId: 10002})` that replaces it.

I've looked at the `_listeners` attribute in the `order` object and thought that maybe I could loop through that and call `stopListening()` on all of the listeners that way?

I couldn't find any clear guides on this matter. Basically the new `listenTo` and `stopListening` functions have confused the hell out me.

Comment: What about just updating the Order?
Initialise it once and on update just reset it to initial state and change `customerId`. In this case all events will be saved.

Comment: If you have a notion of "current order" then you could proxy all the "current order" events through `SessionManager` by having `SessionManager` bind to `"all"` on the order and then everyone else would bind to events on the session manager. Of course the approach that makes sense depends on the specifics of your application.